# Concrete Types or Interfaces for return types for spring beans?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

im currently confused about the Bean registration and creation. My issue is i have a interface with 2 implementations, but at runtime just 1 Bean is registered.
This is ensured by various conditions.
When a concrete bean is created, I want to create another bean. But this is not work, when i return interface types.

A short Example

```
interface Foo{
 String bar()
}

class Foo1 implements Foo
class Foo2 implements Foo

@Configuration
BarConfiguration


@ConditionalOnMissingBean
@ConditionalOnProperty( value = "my.enabled", havingValue = "false" )
Foo foo1(){
return Foo1();
}

@ConditionalOnMissingBean
Foo foo2(){
return Foo2();
}

@ConditonalOnBean(Foo2.class)
Foo2HealthIndicator foo2HealthIndicator(Foo2 foo2){

//todo something
}
```

So if Foo2 is created, I would expect that the Foo2HealthIndicator is created, but is not.
Maybe someone can give a hint why not.

If i change the bean registration from interface return type to concrete class type it works fine.

```
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
@ConditionalOnProperty( value = "my.enabled", havingValue = "false" )
Foo1 foo1(){
return Foo1();
}

@ConditionalOnMissingBean
Foo2 foo2(){
return Foo2();
}
```

Can someone explain to me why the interface type is not working? Or show me a corresponding documentation ?

Answer (score 0):

[`ConditionalOnMissingBean` javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnMissingBean.html):

> Conditional that only matches when the specified bean classes and/or names are not already contained in the BeanFactory.

So in your first example, `foo2` bean is not registered, because there is one already registered.

Solution is to remove `ConditionalOnMissingBean` annotations.

Comment: No foo2 is registered, because the property is not match at foo1.

I will try to remove foo1 at the first example i think is the same result. The indicator bean is not registered with the return type interface.